# Правильная нумерация ПО?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, cms, контроль-версий, движок

Есть версия ПО 2.9.9

Нужно выпустить новую версию, при этом не хотелось бы переходить на 3.0 Так и не смог разобраться, под какой версией выпустить ПО?

**2.9.10? 2.10.1? 2.9.91?**

Да так, чтобы было понятно людям, что эта версия новее предыдущей.

Comment: Может, 2.9.9.1 ? :)

Comment: etki, я, не знаю, может или нет, но почему здесь тогда пишут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F что 1.01 < 1.1 = 1.10 < 1.11 < 1.2 = 1.20. В итоге получается, что 2.10 меньше чем 2.9

Comment: @Sergio потому что это только один из разных примеров (и выше, и ниже приводится пример человеческого семантического версионирования), не говоря уж о том, что википедия не очень хороша как источник таких знаний

Comment: когда коту заняться нечем...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Проблема: вы руководствуетесь принципами визуальной упорядоченности при установке версии. Версионирование не имеет никаких связей с визуальной упорядоченностью.
Конфликт: вы не можете выбрать между виузальной упорядоченностью, которая говорит вам сделать 3.0.0, и принципом мажорного релиза, который осознаете скорее всего по-своему, но понимаете, что мажорный релиз это не "когда все цифры после первой становятся девятками".
Решение: выбрать только одно из двух, потому что принцип мажорной версии запрещает вам скакать, как получится, а визуальная упорядоченность не дает вам использовать двузначное число в качестве одного из компонентов версии.

Как все-таки хоть немного программист я могу лишь призвать сделать выбор в пользу разумного назначения версии. Насколько понял, вы уже читали про семантическое версионирование, но, судя по комментарию, думаю, что попытаться адаптировать конвенцию для вас стоит.

Семантическая версия состоит из трех номеров: major, minor, patch. Они различаются следующими вещами:

- patch-версия инкрементируется при выпуске релиза, закрывающего баги
- minor-версия инкрементируется при выпуске релиза с новым функционалом, не затрагивающем старый
- major версия инкрементируется при выпуске релиза, которым невозможно пользоваться так, как прежде

Поэтому определение "какую версию мне использовать" превращается в довольно простой условный блок:

- Релиз содержит только багфиксы? Инкрементируется patch-компонент, 2.9.10
- Релиз содержит нововведения, но старый функционал остался прежним? 2.10.0
- Релиз содержит нововведения, которые меняют способ использования старого функционала? 3.0.0

Отвечая на вопрос, который тут же появляется - "мне что, инкремнтировать major-версию каждый раз, когда я ломаю обратную совместимость?". Ответ на этот вопрос - да, major-версия должна выпускаться каждый раз, когда какие-то вещи ломаются; это не игра в поддавки и визуальную упорядоченность. Если вас заботит скорость выпуска major-версий - это значит, что вы ломаете слишком много вещей, и какие-то обновления стоит придерживать в ветке до того, как появится моральная готовность выпустить новый major-релиз; на адаптацию к этой модели уйдет некоторое время, но на деле это всего лишь цифры, между которыми нет никакой разницы, версия 2.х.х или 17.х.х - для конечного потребителя это не так важно как то, сможет ли он пользоваться новой версией так же, как старой.

Не пытайтесь воспринимать 2.9.9. как 299. Это **не** число и не поддается правилам инкрементирования чисел.

Comment: Ок, только объясните, почему в вики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F 1.01 < 1.1 = 1.10 < 1.11 < 1.2 = 1.20, из этого получается, что 2.10 меньше чем 2.9

Comment: @Sergio потому что это пример не-семантического версионирования, **сразу следом за которым идет прямо противоположный пример, совпадающий с моим**

Comment: Да, спасибо, этот пример сбил с толку

Comment: Можно еще вопрос? Можно выпустить 2.10.0 beta, а потом 2.10.0 stable? 2.10.0  = 2.10.0 stable?

Comment: @Sergio да ; да

Comment: Я щас хрень напишу, но куда проще версии нумеровать от 1 до 99999, главное не забыть выделить место для 5 целых.

Comment: @АндрейАршинов гиперболизированный пример: вы пишете библиотеку и спустя два года после 299 выпускаете 300. 300 - полностью переписанный релиз, в котором нет ничего от 299. Сразу после релиза 300 оказалось, что в 299 существует критическая уязвимость, которую надо поправить, чтобы те, кто пользовался 299, могли беззаботно взять обновленную версию, а не переезжать на 300. Вопрос: до какой версии обновится 299?

Answer (score 2):

2.9.91 - самое понятное решение. Если бы вы использовали настроенную систему контроля версий, то она сама бы дала нужные цифры (скорее всего, другие).

Вот один из наиболее распространенных подходов:

> Формат номера версии A.B.C.D[r], где:• A – главный номер версии (major
>   version number). • B – вспомогательный номер версии (minor version
>   number). • C – номер сборки, номер логической итерации по работе над
>   функционалом версии A.B (build number). • D – Номер ревизии, сквозной
>   номер назначаемый автоматически программным обеспечением хранения
>   версий (SVN). Номер ревизии SVN должен синхронизироваться с номером
>   ревизии в AssemblyInfo при каждой сборке релиза (revision number). •
>   [r] – условное обозначение релиза.

Подробнее - https://habrahabr.ru/post/119400/

Comment: Да, читал, но с моим случаем не помогло.  В обще до этого версии были только из трех цифр, хотелось бы сохранить эту традицию... Плюс я не видел такую нумерацию ни у кого.

Comment: Нумерация версий - в целом ваше личное дело, главное чтобы система нумерования была понятна и выполняла свои задачи.
PHP вот тоже пропустил версию 6 и перешел от 5.6 к 7, по особым на то причинам.